# .scss not compiling correctly

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I started a new Vue(3) project. In it I have some general style in the App.scss and a HomeView.vue with a HomeView.scss (in the /src/views/Home folder). Styling in both files is applied fine except the .login-div class. When I inspect this style in the browser on the actual div, the result is as the image below

If I put all the css below in the App.scss the style is applied fine.

Does anyone have any idea why the css comes out in this weird way?
Am I looking over something simple?
I've worked with Vue and SASS a little bit, but am not that familiar with the setup and configurations, so maybe I'm missing something there.

```html
.home-view {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.login-div {

    label {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 1rem;
    }

    p {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you converting the sass file to css?

Comment: I use sass-loader for that I believe. This is in my package.json:
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
  }

Comment: It looks like the { are simply converted to [ when selectors are nested. Nested selectors work fine in App.scss though...

Comment: It's unclear if the style is located in HomeView.scss . If it's so, how is it imported? Check the content of CSS that results in this style, this can be done in devtools sources, currently only you can do that

Comment: Do you define the style tag as scss, `<style lang="scss"></style>` ?
  It's the only selector where you are using scss (nested selectors)

Comment: Whow that's it @Amaury Hanser. I forgot the lang attribute :\ Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

As Amaury Hanser mentions above I forgot to put the lang="scss" in the style tag.

In my HomeView.vue I had:

```html
<style>
  @import "HomeView.scss";
</style>
```

Which should be:

```html
<style lang='scss'>
  @import "HomeView.scss";
</style>
```